# HTML Images Error

Tags: javascript, html

all of the icons I have for this menu are all shifted to the right in the menu, what could cause this on my other pages the images appear correctly

```
document.getElementById("div11").innerHTML="<i>Apprentice Daily Entries</i><br> <img id='img2'  src='icons/file_add.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div21").innerHTML="<i>Unsigned Leader Checklists</i><br> <img id='img2'  src='icons/file_search.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div12").innerHTML="<i>Email All</i><br> <img id='img1' src='icons/coming_soon.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div22").innerHTML="<i>Calendar</i> <br> <img id='img2' src='icons/coming_soon.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div13").innerHTML="<i>Coming Soon</i> <br> <img id='img1' src='icons/coming_soon.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div23").innerHTML="<i>Coming Soon</i> <br> <img id='img2' src='icons/coming_soon.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div14").innerHTML="<i>Coming Soon</i><br> <img id='img1' src='icons/coming_soon.png'></img>" 
document.getElementById("div24").innerHTML="<i>Coming Soon</i><br> <img id='img2' src='icons/coming_soon.png'></img>"
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question, including the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Atleast terminate the JavaScript lines

Answer (score 0):

First, you can optimise your code like that :

```
setMyHtml('div11', 'Apprentice Daily Entries','file_add.png' );
setMyHtml('div21', 'Unsigned Leader Checklists','file_search.png' );
setMyHtml('div12', 'Email All','coming_soon.png' );
setMyHtml('div22', 'Calendar','coming_soon.png' );
setMyHtml('div13', 'Coming Soon','coming_soon.png' );
setMyHtml('div23', 'Coming Soon','coming_soon.png' );
setMyHtml('div14', 'Coming Soon','coming_soon.png' );
setMyHtml('div24', 'Coming Soon','coming_soon.png' );

function setMyHtml(id, text, img){
    var imgId= ""; // here, generate an UNIQUE ID for your image 
    var myHtml = "<i>"+text+"</i><br> <img id='"+imgId+"' src='icons/"+img+"' alt='a text describe your img' />" 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = myHtml ;
}
```

In your example, your javascript is not good; 
after every line you forget the "**;**" char.

Also, your HTML, is not good: 
 the 'img' tag ([official doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html)) is an autoClose tag like that :

```
<img src="myImg.png" alt="my Img" /> <!-- That is good -->
<img src="myImg.png" alt="my Img" ></img> <!-- That is wrong -->
<img src="myImg.png" ></img> <!-- That is very wrong -->
```

And, you have forgotten the "alt" attribute. This attribute is the 'alternative text', it's appear when your 'src' attribute path is wrong. And is read by the software that allows blind people to use the internet ... If you can see shows, it's just your 'src' attribute is wrong...

```
<img src="myImg.png" alt="my Img" /> <!-- Img from the location where is the JS-->
<img src="folder/myImg.png" alt="my Img" /> <!-- Img from the folder 'foolder' where is the JS -->
<img src="/folder/myImg.png" alt="my Img" /> <!-- Img from the folder 'foolder' one level before where is the JS  -->
```

And, id's of all tag in the same page must be unique!! ([official documentation of the HTML Id attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2))

Finally, for this type of error, you can, check your HTML, **AND** your JavaScript  with [the developer tools box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) include in all browsers!

And, you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for learn to use Stackeoverflow in 2 min ;P